# pandas dataframe groupby by column position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a function that does group by on a pandas dataframe. The problem is my dataframe can have variable number of columns. I want to aggregate: sum the last column by the first column. The name of the last column is different, but, the name of the first column is fixed.

How could I achieve the group by? I tried using iloc and by getting the column name of the last column using df.columns[-1], but, none of these tricks seem to work.

Are there any better ways to achieve this than changing the last column name to some common value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[-1]].sum()` should work.

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,1,2,2],
    'b': [1,2,3,4]
})

df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[-1]].sum()
#a
#1    3
#2    7
#Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: if I have multiple columns group by, how to do that? The method above does not support multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Series` selected by `iloc`, data borrowed by @Psidom:

```
s = df.iloc[:, -1].groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]).sum()
print (s)
a
1    3
2    7
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to mention that I need to summarize multiple columns. So, I want to use `agg` alongwith groupby. I am getting error `IndexError: too many indices for array` when I use iloc inside the agg function.

Comment: hmm, so you need `s = df.iloc[:, [-1, -2]].groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]).sum()` ?

Comment: I need `s = df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]).agg(df.iloc[:,-1]:['sum'],'df.iloc[:,1]:['sum'],df.iloc[:,-1]:['count'],'df.iloc[:,1]:['count'])`